# vsync lags: xorg gnome window dragging

Tags: nvidia, xorg, video, chromium

If I run for example this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCXX91QnZSg and open another tab every window I drag will lag and potentially freeze the DE for a minute. I have sadly an NVIDIA card.

I am using brave browser which has its own window borders. I think gets worse the longer a video is running because It doesn't happen right now when I watch the video.

Running anything less than 4K works well and it's **definitely not a resouce problem** (network, cpu or graphics card). My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 super.

The lag is noticeable if a 4K video runs in the foreground but there's no freezing issue.

I don't have a 4K monitor.

**New:**

If I run glxgears, the same happens with every window.
It doesn't happen when vsync is disabled.

**Conclusion:**

VSYNC triggers the lag. Is it X11 or the nvidia driver?
*Wayland works fine.*

Comment: Do you have the Nvidia drivers installed? And have you disabled Secure Boot in UEFI?

Comment: me too. If the opened tab of chrome has a video that is running (also if chrome is on foreground), dragging windows result lagging and sometime freeze the system.
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
AMD® Ryzen 7 4800h
GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile
NVIDIA driver 515

Comment: Also seems to happen on my website which has a fancy moving background.

Comment: glxgears triggers the same

Comment: where can bugs be reported, bugs like these?

Comment: Have you tried Wayland?

Comment: @davegallant no, I have not

Comment: wayland works fine, so I'll add this